# Launching applications on remote windows xp from ubuntu 10.04 machine

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, remote-access

I have ubuntu 10.04 installed on my machine. I want to execute commands on remote windows xp machine ( I have username and password of admin account of remote machine ) so as to launch application like Internet Explorer, Notepad or some bat script. Is there any command line utility to do this via ubuntu? I tried rdesktop, winexe, ssh, telnet but they are not much of use. Can you please suggest some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install software on the Windows machine, you can use a Virtual Network Computing software ([UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) and [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) are good).

This will let you connect and interact as if you were in front of the machine.

Comment: But I don't want GUI here. I just want to operate these operations via command line.